# javax.mail - "535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful" due to javax.mail upgrade (v1.3.1 to v1.5.2)

Tags: java, email, authentication, smtp, mail-server

## 1 - Problem

A client of my company is about to upgrade the version of our software. In his test environment for the upgrade, he discovered that he cannot a send mail through the application anymore (he didn't change the configuration of his SMTP server, which is the same he uses for his production environment where everything is fine).

**We figured out with a test that this "bug" is caused by the upgrade which changes the javax.mail jar from version 1.3.1 to version 1.5.2**. To verify this, we gave the client a .class to execute which send an email, and if it uses the 1.3.1 version of the javax.mail jar, it works, but if it uses the 1.5.2 version, it does not work. The client writes the server configuration in a property file.

#### Server configuration

```
mail.smtp.host=<ip_adress>
mail.smtp.port=25

mail.from=clientCompany@clientDomain
mail.to=recipient@clientDomain

mail.smtp.user=clientCompany@clientDomain
mail.smtp.password=<client_pwd>

mail.subject=whatever
mail.body=whatever
```

#### Java (light version)

```
Properties systemProperties = System.getProperties();
systemProperties.putAll(fileProperties);
Session mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(systemProperties);
Transport tr = mailSession.getTransport("smtp");
tr.connect(mailSmtpHost, Integer.valueOf(mailSmtpPort), mailSmtpUser, mailSmtpPassword);
tr.sendMessage(mailToSend, mailToSend.getAllRecipients());
```

#### Log (if javax.mail 1.5.2)

```
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.providers
DEBUG: Tables of loaded providers
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Class Name: {com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Oracle], com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Oracle]}
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Protocol: {imaps=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Oracle], imap=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Oracle], smtps=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Oracle], pop3=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Oracle], pop3s=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Oracle], smtp=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]}
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.address.map
...
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "<ip_adress>", port 25, isSSL false
...
DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "<ip_adress>", port: 25
...
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "37748736"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "PIPELINING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "DSN", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "STARTTLS", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "X-ANONYMOUSTLS", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "AUTH", arg "NTLM"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "X-EXPS", arg "GSSAPI NTLM"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "BINARYMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "CHUNKING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "XRDST", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Attempt to authenticate using mechanisms: NTLM
DEBUG NTLM: type 1 message: 4E 54 4C 4D 53 53 50 00 01 00 00 00 03 B2 00 00 0A 00 0A 00 2E 00 00 00 0E 00 0E 00 20 00 00 00 50 42 54 4B 41 50 4D 4F 42 49 4C 45 30 31 42 54 4B 44 2E 4C 4F 43 41 4C
DEBUG SMTP: AUTH NTLM command trace suppressed
DEBUG NTLM: type 3 message: 4E 54 4C 4D 53 53 50 00 03 00 00 00 18 00 18 00 9E 00 00 00 18 00 18 00 B6 00 00 00 14 00 14 00 40 00 00 00 2E 00 2E 00 54 00 00 00 1C 00 1C 00 82 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 CE 00 00 00 01 82 00 00 42 00 54 00 4B 00 44 00 2E 00 4C 00 4F 00 43 00 41 00 4C 00 65 00 62 00 61 00 6E 00 6B 00 69 00 6E 00 67 00 2D 00 62 00 74 00 6B 00 40 00 62 00 74 00 6B 00 6E 00 65 00 74 00 2E 00 63 00 6F 00 6D 00 50 00 42 00 54 00 4B 00 41 00 50 00 4D 00 4F 00 42 00 49 00 4C 00 45 00 30 00 31 00 1F F4 4F 84 82 68 AD 69 9E D3 84 53 11 98 FE 72 78 06 75 79 03 E4 04 6F A5 F5 FA E5 F7 B0 E5 98 CD 25 20 B5 10 04 B9 64 B5 A8 2E 2F D9 C5 64 B7
DEBUG SMTP: AUTH NTLM failed
javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport$Authenticator.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:892)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:814)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:728)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:364)
at MailSendTest.sendMail(MailSendTest.java:87)
at MailSendTest.main(MailSendTest.java:132)
```

#### Log (if javax.mail 1.3.1)

```
DEBUG: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/java64/jdk1.6.0_30/jre/lib/javamail.providers (No such file or directory)
DEBUG: !anyLoaded
DEBUG: not loading resource: /META-INF/javamail.providers
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.providers
DEBUG: Tables of loaded providers
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Class Name: {com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Sun Microsystems, Inc]}
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Protocol: {imap=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], pop3=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Sun Microsystems, Inc], smtp=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc]}
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.address.map
DEBUG: !anyLoaded
DEBUG: not loading resource: /META-INF/javamail.address.map
DEBUG: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/java64/jdk1.6.0_30/jre/lib/javamail.address.map (No such file or directory)
...
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "<ip_adress>", port 25
...
DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "<ip_adress>", port: 25
...
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "37748736"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "PIPELINING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "DSN", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "STARTTLS", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "X-ANONYMOUSTLS", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "AUTH", arg "NTLM"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "X-EXPS", arg "GSSAPI NTLM"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "BINARYMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "CHUNKING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "XRDST", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Attempt to authenticate
DEBUG SMTP: use8bit false
MAIL FROM:<clientCompany@clientDomain>
250 2.1.0 Sender OK
RCPT TO:<recipient@clientDomain>
250 2.1.5 Recipient OK
DEBUG SMTP: Verified Addresses
DEBUG SMTP:   recipient@clientDomain
DATA
354 Start mail input; end with <CRLF>.<CRLF>
Message-ID: <181398600.1528806707522.JavaMail.clientCompany@clientDomain>
From: clientCompany@clientDomain
To: recipient@clientDomain
Subject: whatever
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
        boundary="----=_Part_0_1199604121.1528806707440"

------=_Part_0_1199604121.1528806707440
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

whatever
------=_Part_0_1199604121.1528806707440--
```

## 2 - Solutions ?

When I try using the .class with javax.mail 1.5.2 and the SMTP server configuration of my company, it works. I cannot reproduce their error. So our guess is that it may come from their mail server.

I read multiple topics about this problem but could not find any solution yet. May be changing the port from 25 to 587, which is the recommended port, but I really don't see why it would change anything (plus it works with 25 or 587 on my computer).

Comment: I realised that at work we use the LOGIN authentication mechanism, but the log of our client clearly shows that he uses the NTLM authentification mechanism with v1.5.2, but obviously no mechanism at all with v1.3.1. 

The javamail doc also states that NTLM authentication support for SMTP was added in v1.4.3 (see https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/CHANGES.txt), so that is why. Unfortunately I cannot make the version v1.5.2 NOT USE the NTLM mechanism and behave like v1.3.1, so I have to understand how to correctly use this mechanism.